# How to create a Multipass instance with custom installed softwares and share it with others

Tags: virtualization, ros, multipass

I would like my students to use a specific version of Ubuntu with custom-installed software (ROS and Gazebo, software for robotic applications). In addition, my students might be running Windows, Mac OS, or Linux.

To simplify the installation on their side, I am thinking of using Multipass and sharing with them a pre-installed instance of Ubuntu with Gazebo and ROS already installed. Is it possible? If yes, how to create this instance, and how to share it with my students?

Answer (score 1):

Multipass, at this time, does not support import/export/backup/restore functionality that you need to share machine images. It is on their roadmap, but not near-term.

- Source: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/can-i-backup-the-multipass-image/32533

Multipass is compatible with cloud-init scripts (see https://ubuntu.com/blog/using-cloud-init-with-multipass)

Multipass-created VMs can also use custom shell scripts to guide customization.